# rosrun rviz rviz error.please help me

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `rosrun rviz rviz` in groovy,
it warns:

```
viki@ROS:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12class_loader11ClassLoader37has_unmananged_instance_been_created_E
```

who can help me? please,thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58019/rosrun-rviz-rviz---error.please-help-me/) by [Xjayjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/4415/xjayjay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-03-13**:
Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` recently?
What's your version of the `ros-groovy-rviz` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, make sure all your RViz plugins are compiled against your current version of RViz and pluginlib, in case you have source-based plugin packages in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0